# Java scalable frameworks usage on Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

We are using Google App Engine for back-end development. **We're considering the scalability, change of server and data movement to another cloud platform in future, as well the robustness in application**. Please suggest the frameworks that can be used in Google App Engine (Java based).

1. End point exposure/Rest web services
2. ORM/database connection
3. Service and db layer integration
4. Logging
5. Unit testing
6. etc

Please add any points that I may have missed.

**Update**: The reason behind asking this question is that when we start development we will get a hell lot of samples, for example:

1. Rest web services - we have Spring Boot/Spring rest web services
2. DB - we have JDO, Google Datastore, etc.
3. For easy access we can use Spring Core.

If we browse through information on Google App Engine Java development, we're unable to find a list of advantages/disadvantages. It's correct that we have many options. While answering please also consider the bolded words. The question definitely looks simple from an angle, but it's a serious issue for the fresh development.

Answer (score 0):

There are several products and services within Google App Engine that will help you out building scalable backends in Java using App Engine. Here are some examples based on what you may be looking for:

[**Endpoints Frameworks on App Engine in Java**](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/get-started-frameworks-java) - helps with developing, deploying and managing APIs on any Google Cloud backend.

[**Objectify**](https://github.com/objectify/objectify) - a Java data access API, specifically designed for the GAE datastore.

[**Stackdriver logging**](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/service/appengine-logs) - provides facilities for importing, viewing, storing and retrieving timestamped logs from apps running in GCP.

[**Unit Testing in Java**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/localunittesting) - which allows you to test the quality of your code after you’ve written it, as well as to improve your development process as you go along.

**UPDATE:** [**This article**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/scalability) on **Designing for Scale** is a good place to start for best practices on scalability in App Engine. Regarding robustness, that’s a given using App Engine, as it is designed as a robust development environment for written applications. If you’re considering moving to another cloud platform in future, take a look at the GCP documentation on exporting data for each specific product you wish to export from.

You may find these articles on Spring Framework useful, which focus on the benefits and best practices.

- **[Announcing Spring Cloud GCP—integrating your favorite Java framework with Google Cloud](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2018/02/announcing-Spring-Cloud-GCP-integrating-your-favorite-Java-framework-with-Google-Cloud.html)**
- **[Optimizing Spring Framework for App Engine Applications](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/spring_optimization)**

Comment: Hi Ryan, Thanks for the reply, i have updated the question.